# Dimension too large with width=0.75\textwidth

Tags: dimensions, includegraphics

I am trying to insert a picture with text next to it (not caption) using xymatrix in a document but despite that I set the width of the picture plus text to 0.75 of the text width I get dimensions too large error. Here is the script I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,openany,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}

\geometry{verbose}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\linespread{1.5}

\topmargin -1.0cm

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}

\footskip 0pt

\textwidth = 24.7cm

\textheight = 37cm

\evensidemargin = 0pt

\marginparsep = 0pt

\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage[all,color,dvips]{xy}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centerline{
\xymatrix{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, clip=true]{picture.eps} 
 &\raisebox{10pc}{\fbox{\parbox[c]{0.3\textwidth}{Some text}
 }
 }
 } 
} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where `picture.eps` is

```
%%BoundingBox: 14 14 342 5050
```

It gives the same error also if I don't use xymatrix and fbox and just put the picture and text in a figure.

I would be very thankful if somebody can give me an advice

Thanks in advance

smaller example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}


\xymatrix{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, clip=true]{picture.eps} 
 &
 }

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Possibly a malformed EPS file. Can you try with a different one just for testing?

Comment: unrelated but you shouldn't use `\centerline` in latex.

Comment: I have used other eps files with same syntax and works it also works with the picture with which I am having problems if a rotate it horizontally (it is a photo which I want to place vertically)

Comment: The vertical dimension fits the page so it shouldn't e a problem. It also works fine vertically if I don't include the text.

Comment: The posted example does not give the error in the title but does give `! Paragraph ended before \centerline was complete.`

Comment: OK thanks I removed the spurious blanks so people can reproduce the error

Comment: Please, check the numbers in the bounding box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get this error for example from the document below

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \Gin@nat@height 

l.10 ...th=0.45\textwidth, clip=true]{picture.eps}

?
```

Here the original size is 1pt wide and 1000pt high so when you scale the image so that the width is .45\textwidth, the height becomes larger than TeX's maximum dimension.

```
\begin{filecontents}{picture.eps}
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1 1000
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth, clip=true]{picture.eps}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

The issue is actually unrelated to the image, that scales as expected and makes a box of size roughly 300pt by 400pt which is not excessively big however it fails in the xy package arithmetic as can be seen by the following example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\xymatrix{\rule{300pt}{400pt}
&x
}

\end{document}
```

This produces the same error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \dimen@ 

l.9 }
```

Comment: This is the entry in the eps file %%BoundingBox: 14 14 342 505. The picture by itself (hence it height) fit in the page and doesn't give error if I don't use text next to it. Sorry if I can't explain clear.

Comment: I added a complete tex script that reproduces my error

Comment: That is the only boundingbox I could find in the eps. The dimensions of the picture are 2042 (height) by 1363 (width) pixels. Maybe this discrepancy is the problem, I converted it from jpg to eps with gimp.